# In Angular 7, how do I extract the result from an Observable?

Tags: angular, service, observable, angular7

I'm using Angular 7 with a Rail 5 back-end.  I have a service that I use to interact with the Rails 5 back-end ...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class CurrencyService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  index() {
    let ret = this._http.get<Object[]>('api/currencies').map(r => r);
    console.log(ret);
    return ret;
  }

  refresh() {
    return this._http.get<Object[]>('api/refresh').map(r => r);
  }
}
```

I have this in my src/app/app.component.ts file that interacts with the service ...

```
import { CurrencyService } from './../shared/currency.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  currencies = [];
  title = 'app';
  apiStatus: string;
  constructor(private _currencySrv: CurrencyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._currencySrv.index<Object[]>().subscribe(
      currencies => this.currencies = currencies);
  }

  refresh() {
    this._currencySrv.refresh<Object[]>().subscribe(
      currencies => this.currencies = currencies);
  }

}
```

How do I extract the result of the call to "index" and "refresh" from the Observable object returned?  When I try and iterate over the "currencies" member var using ngFor, I get the error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (AppComponent.html:4)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14735)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13849)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13850)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.js:14635)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.js:11619)
    at eval (core.js:5918)
```

I think because the result is wrapped in a field called "data" but I don't know the proper way of extracting the field wihtout all kinds of compilation errors when I try and start my Angular server through "ng serve".

**Edit:** In src/app/app.component.html I have

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<ul>
  <ng-container *ngIf="currencies?.length">
  <li *ngFor="let currency of currencies">
    <div>{{currency.name}}</div>
    <div>{{currency.country}}</div>
    <div>{{currency.rate / 100}}</div>
  </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Refresh

yet no data displays ever, even though

Comment: The error you get has nothing to do with the code you posted: it's happening to access the property name of something, and the code you posted doesn't do that. Note however that `.map(r => r);` is absolutely useless: what do you think that does. Also, you're using a pre-Angular6 way of using Observables. The current version is Angular 8. Why are you using such an old version? Using `this._currencySrv.index<Object[]>()` doesn't make sense, since index is not a generic method. I'm surprised it compiles.

Comment: Finally why do you use the type Object, instead of an interface that actually describes the shape of the objects you get from your backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of issues you need to correct in your code. @JBNizet seems to have already mentioned most of the issues.

Let's begin with your service first.

- As mentioned, if you are using `rxjs6` in your Angular application, you can use the `rxjs6` pipeable operators syntax instead of the `rxjs5` syntax you have used. (Source: [docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration#howto-convert-to-pipe-syntax))
- Change the `import` location for `Observable` to `rxjs` and `map` to `rxjs/operators`. (Source: [docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration#import-paths))
- `import { Http } from '@angular/http';` is redundant. This package is deprecated. Use `@angular/common/http` instead. (Source: [docs](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularhttp))
- Don't use `Object` as it refers to non-primitive boxed objects. (Source: [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html)). Instead use `any` or better yet, create an interface that defines your backend response.
- The way your `map` is currently written, it doesn't even do anything. Instead, since your backend returns an object with `data` in it, you can use the `map` to return just the `data`.
- I'm not sure what your `refresh` api does, but if it just getting the same data as the `currencies` api, then it seems unnecessary. I'll leave it as is in my answer as I'm unsure if it contains other data.

With all this in mind, your `CurrencyService` will now look like

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { CurrenciesResponse, Currency } from 'path/to/your/interface';

@Injectable()
export class CurrencyService {
    constructor(
        private _http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    index(): Observable<Currency[]> {
        return this._http.get<CurrenciesResponse>('api/currencies').pipe(
            map((res: CurrenciesResponse) => res.data)
        );
    }

    refresh(): Observable<Currency[]> {
        return this._http.get<CurrenciesResponse>('api/refresh').pipe(
            map((res: CurrenciesResponse) => res.data)
        );
    }
}
```

Where your interfaces will look something like this

```js
export interface CurrenciesResponse {
    data: Currency[];
    // Add other backend response properties here if present
}

export interface Currency {
    name: string;
    country: string;
    rate: number;
    // ...
}
```

Add your interfaces in a separate file and import them wherever necessary.

In your component, there seems to be only one issue. You don't need to provide a type argument when you invoke `index()` and `refresh()` from `currencyService` as they are not generic methods. Your IDE should usually warn you about this with an error like `Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1`

```js
currencies: Currency[] = [];
title: string = 'app';
apiStatus: string;

constructor(
    private _currencySrv: CurrencyService
) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this._currencySrv.index().subscribe(currencies => {
        this.currencies = currencies;
    });
}

refresh() {
    this._currencySrv.refresh().subscribe(currencies => {
        this.currencies = currencies;
    });
}
```

Lastly, in your HTML, the `ngIf` is redundant as even `ngFor` will not print anything unless `currencies` contains data.

```html
<ul *ngFor="let currency of currencies">
    <li>
        <div>{{currency.name}}</div>
        <div>{{currency.country}}</div>
        <div>{{currency.rate / 100}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-in-memory-service). I have used [`angular-in-memory-web-api`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-in-memory-web-api) for the API response.

Comment: @Dave - I have added a working example on StackBlitz of the solution.

Comment: I'm getting a number of compilation errors from your solution, so I'll start with just one.  The line, "this.currencies = currencies" in the "app.component.ts" file within the "ngOnInit" method is giving the error, "Type 'Currencies' is not assignable to type 'Currencies[]'".  And then it says, "Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Currencies'."

Comment: This can be possible only if your API is returning a single `Currency` object rather than an array of `Currency`. Can you confirm what you're API is returning? Check out my StackBlitz example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-in-memory-service), in the `console` I have shown what the API response looks like (by using `tap` in the service to `console` the response). Does it look similar to your API response?

Comment: The previous error was because I had copied your code wrong -- I had Observable<Currency> instead of Observable<Currency[]>.  However, I'm getting a JS error rendering the HTML.  I opened a separate question about it because I'm not sure if its related to what you have, even though I "think" I copied what you have exactly -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57681637/how-to-resolve-angular-7-error-trying-to-diff-only-arrays-and-iterables-are .

Comment: I've figured out your issue. Looks like there's a problem with your API response. It's sending you the data as a string. I would ideally suggest you change the API response to an array of objects but for now, you could easily fix this by just parsing the response before you pass it to `this.currencies`. So instead of `this.currencies = currencies;`, you will now have `this.currencies = JSON.parse(currencies);` Your IDE will give you an error like `Argument of type 'Currency[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.` because you are using a string instead of `Currency[]`

Comment: As I mentioned, the best fix for this would be to modify the API response. If that's not an option, you will have to modify the types in your application so that you won't get the `TypeError` warnings. Let me know if that's the case and I shall modify the type assertion in my answer to satisfy your current response

Comment: Yeah I think modifying the API (a Rails app) is the way to go b/c when I applied your suggestion to the TS file I got a "Argument of type 'Currency[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'" upon "ng serve" startup.  It's odd though, b/c my Rails controller returns "render json: { data: currency_list.to_json }", which looks like JSON to me, but I guess it's a string as you say.

Comment: I'm no Rails expert, but can you try  `{ data: currency_list.as_json }` instead?

Comment: Ah that results in a syntax error.  When I call the API on its own, using curl or wget or something, what should the response look like?  Should it start with a "[" or a quote or a "{"?

Comment: Since you're API response is an object with `data` in it and your `data` is an array of objects. It should look something like this `{ data: [{...}, {...}, {...}] }`. There shouldn't be any quotes. If there are quotes then it's a string

Comment: I'm confused about the role of quotes, but calling the Rails API directly looks like this (I added the "...") -- {"data":"[{\"id\":2,\"na ... 3.325Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2019-08-16T20:07:59.373Z\"}]"}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198599/discussion-between-nash11-and-dave).

Comment: Its ok, I got it to work by adjusting the API endpoint.  Thx again

Answer (score 0):

That’s because `currencies` are not filled with data yet. As the template renders before the request is completed. Wrapping the list in the `<ng-container *ngIf=“currencies?.length”>` will help.

And everything JB Nizet wrote in the comments is absolute truth.

**Update:**

app.component.ts

```
import { CurrencyService } from './../shared/currency.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  currencies = [];
  title = 'app';
  apiStatus: string;

  constructor(private _currencySrv: CurrencyService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._currencySrv.index().subscribe(
      currencies => {
        console.log(currencies);
        this.currencies = currencies;
      });
  }

  refresh() {
    this._currencySrv.refresh().subscribe(currencies => this.currencies = currencies);
  }
}
```

currency.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface CurrencyWrapper {
  data: Currency[];
}

export interface Currency {
  name: string,
  country: string,
  rate: number,
}

@Injectable()
export class CurrencyService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  index() {
    return this._http.get<CurrencyWrapper>('api/currencies').pipe(map(currencies => currencies.data));
  }

  refresh() {
    return this._http.get<CurrencyWrapper>('api/refresh').pipe(map(currencies => currencies.data));
  }
}
```

Note: it would be better to define interfaces in the separate files. Also you can refactor the code according to your needs.

Comment: I edited my question to add the app.component.html file with your suggestion.  However, still, despite the fact that I can see through debugging data returned in the service call to the back-end, nothing displays on the front-end.  JBNizet nicely describes all the things taht are wrong witih the code but I don't see any suggestions in his extensively long comment about how to correct them.

Comment: @Dave can you please create a stackblitz so it’s easier to find the error?

Comment: Way to correct them: 1. define an interface describing the shape of the objects that you receive from the backend. Let's callthis interface `Currency`. 2. Replace `http.get<Object[]>` by `http.get<{data: Currency[];}>`. 3. Replace `.map(r => r)` by `.map(r => r.data)`. 4. Replace `this._currencySrv.index<Object[]>()` by `this._currencySrv.index()`. Same for the other method. 5. Run ng serve and make sure there is 0 error being listed. 6. Post the JSON you get in your question to know what you actually receive from the backend.

Comment: Oh, and since you are actually using Angular 7, replace `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` by `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';` and replace `.map(r => r)` by `.pipe(map(r => r.data))`.

Comment: @Dave I updated the answer according to your other comments. So just do the `ng-container` thing and add `.data` in the subscribe to get the actual array of the data.

Comment: Went out of town and just got back and saw your update.  Unfortunately I get a " error TS2558: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1." on startup, complaining about the line, "this._currencySrv.index<Object[]>().subscribe("

Comment: So somewhere `index()` is called with an argument. Try to find it and remove, can say more when I don't see the code. And there's a good catch from JB Nizet about type, it should be either corresponding interface or at least `any` instead of `Object[]`

Comment: @Dave Also remove `.map(r => r)` from `index()` and `refresh()`

Comment: Hi, I removed the ".map" stuff as you suggested.  The only other place in the entire codebase where the string "index" occurs is in the service class, as it is posted in my question.  Note that upon running the "ng serve" startup command there is also a second compile error, "(25,5): error TS2558: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1" complaining about the line, "this._currencySrv.refresh<Object[]>().subscribe".

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz example with the problem?

Comment: Maybe -- I've never used stackblitz before.  Let me see if there is somewhere that I can upload the zip file.  The code is very minimal and not much beyond what I've posted here.

Comment: Ok, I uploaded a ZIP of everything here -- https://github.com/rubyangular7demo/currency-calculator .  Only download the file "everything.zip".  In it, there are two directories, one is for the Rails back-end and the other is the angular frontend where the code I referenced is located.  Thx.

Comment: @Dave the obvious problem I see from the first glance is that you don't implement `OnInit` interface. You have to add it to your `AppComponent` like so `export class AppComponent implements OnInit {` and import `OnInit` it from `@angular/core`. That's why `ngOnInit()` method was never called.

Comment: Second thing, remove generic type `Object[]` from the `index()` and `refresh()` in the `AppComponent` as you don't have them defined in the service. That's why you had the "arguments..." error.

Comment: And the last thing, add proper interface to your data. I'll update my answer

Comment: Hi, Thx, so I added the code as you have it, but now get the compile error, 'Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Currency[]'' twice in the service class.

Comment: Which is correct, `CurrencyWrapper` has the `data` property

Comment: What's correct -- the compilation errors?  Those are generated by the code you provided.  What code would I use so that I don't get the compilation errors?

Comment: Use CurrencyWrapper instead of Currency[]

Comment: Thanks but I have "return this._http.get<CurrencyWrapper>" just as you have it in the service yet still I get those compile errors when I fire things up.

Answer (score 0):

Since the result is wrapped inside an object 'data', all you need to do is assign the object that you need upon the observable emitting the value.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this._currencySrv.index<Object[]>().subscribe(
      currencies => this.currencies = currencies.data);
  }
  refresh() {
    this._currencySrv.refresh<Object[]>().subscribe(
      currencies => this.currencies = currencies.data);
  }
```

Comment: This won't compile. `currencies` is of type Object[], and there is no property named `data` in an array of Object.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the array currencies. Do you want to extract the data object inside the currency element?

Comment: @Kaushik, When I run "console.log(currencies);" in the block you reference, it outputs "{data: "[{"id":2,"name":"EUR","rate":1,"country":"Europe", … 3.325Z","updated_at":"2019-08-16T20:07:59.373Z"}]"}".  The "..." is what I added to cut down on the output, but hopefully this gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Few steps to do:

### Don't map results into an undefined object.

> let ret = this._http.get<**Object**[]>('api/currencies').map(r => r);

It isn't good practice. Better is to create a model. Then TypeScript will know what properties are in the object. Look at this:

```
export class CurrencyReponse {   
   name: string;  
   country: string;  
   rate: number; 
}
```

and then after importing that please use:

```
index(): Observable<CurrencyReponse[]> {
   return this.http.get<CurrencyReponse[]>('api/currencies');
}
```

Same for refresh method.

### Then when consuming in component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this._currencySrv.index<CurrencyReponse[]>().subscribe(
      response => this.currencies = response.data);
  }

  refresh() {
    this._currencySrv.refresh<CurrencyReponse[]>().subscribe(
      response => this.currencies = response.data);
  }
```

### Bonus Tip

Here you are secured by *ngFor loop but sometimes if you don't have it and you would like to show something that can be initialized later then you can use *ngIf condition. For example:

```
    <div *ngIf="currency.name">{{currency.name}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="currency.country">{{currency.country}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="currency.rate">{{currency.rate / 100}}</div>
```

Comment: To be clear, you recommend creating a separate class/file, CurrencyReponse.  So whenever I modify my model, I will need to update this class, my migration, and then any back-end class the Rails API references, is that right?  That seems like a lot.  I thought Angular was supposed to simplify development and it seems it's just adding a bunch more steps in this case.

Comment: Yes, I can recommend this way. Angular wasn't created to simplify development :) It was created to organize and structure code like it is on backend where likely you are creating separate files for your models. Just look what is an Angular base language - TypeScript. It is indicating order, typing, structure more than dynamism and fast programming. If you would like to "simplify development" on frontend then I can recommend React for you. Just please be aware that both have some advantages and disadvantages.